# Has anyone else experience this? Browsers only cache my Next.js app build artifacts and displays them to the client

Tags: aws-amplify, browser-cache, next.js13

I'm using app router from Next.js 13.4.2 on my app. On its initial load, the app opens the way it should and everything works fine but I noticed that after the app sits long enough for the browser to fetch page content from it's cache, it replaces the original content of the page with the page build artifacts. The website is currently hosted on AWS amplify.

I didn't notice this behaviour when the app was hosted on vercel.

This is what shows up on the browser

```
1:HL["/_next/static/media/7777133e901cd5ed-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 2:HL["/_next/static/media/916d3686010a8de2-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 3:HL["/_next/static/media/9a881e2ac07d406b-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 4:HL["/_next/static/media/bd427f25ac24d036-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 5:HL["/_next/static/media/d36a2a2bb416f59e-s.p.woff2",{"as":"font","type":"font/woff2"}] 6:HL["/_next/static/css/2a07d734a20a99b3.css",{"as":"style"}] 7:HL["/_next/static/css/ecd948767e096f78.css",{"as":"style"}] 0:[[["",{"children":["__PAGE__",{}]},"$undefined","$undefined",true],"$L8",[[["$","link","0",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/2a07d734a20a99b3.css","precedence":"next"}],["$","link","1",{"rel":"stylesheet","href":"/_next/static/css/ecd948767e096f78.css","precedence":"next"}]],["$L9",["$","meta",null,{"name":"next-size-adjust"}]]]]] a:HL["/_next/static/css/458cf75f1ee9813b.css",{"as":"style"}] b:I{"id":"5227","chunks":["201:static/chunks/201-b763b97b8d16f706.js","185:static/chunks/app/layout-350020619d648b75.js"],"name":"","async":false} c:I{"id":"9544","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-eccc90b774de8c50.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-942d23a6246cf16c.js","139:static/chunks/139-b08bf36040abf8bb.js"],"name":"","async":false} d:I{"id":"99","chunks":["272:static/chunks/webpack-eccc90b774de8c50.js","667:static/chunks/2443530c-942d23a6246cf16c.js","139:static/chunks/139-b08bf36040abf8bb.js"],"name":"","async":false} e:I{"id":"9288","chunks":["776:static/chunks/b7d461da-c24d426981069a69.js","358:static/chunks/ae573a17-86c3c0dbf6820279.js","11:static/chunks/11-ada55797f12a86c7.js","414:static/chunks/414-737d93b2fc27a9fe.js","553:static/chunks/553-0c921218202d70d5.js","798:static/chunks/app/privacy/layout-f55345026eeff814.js"],"name":"","async":false} f:I{"id":"2011","chunks":["821:static/chunks/1418c200-705f4a11b96a8412.js","739:static/chunks/543ac898-9e7c2265ce202fd3.js","11:static/chunks/11-ada55797f12a86c7.js","348:static/chunks/348-e537d997b144ed0c.js","201:static/chunks/201-b763b97b8d16f706.js","549:static/chunks/549-0ee789f6816fec15.js","384:static/chunks/384-e052fd0b08e9ac2f.js","857:static/chunks/app/events/[id]/page-234115e5ba29cda9.js"],"name":"","async":false} 10:I{"id":"414","chunks":["414:static/chunks/414-737d93b2fc27a9fe.js","348:static/chunks/348-e537d997b144ed0c.js","201:static/chunks/201-b763b97b8d16f706.js","549:static/chunks/549-0ee789f6816fec15.js","384:static/chunks/384-e052fd0b08e9ac2f.js","236:static/chunks/app/company/career/[id]/page-b7775bbcac1a1e2e.js"],"name":"","async":false} 11:I{"id":"1937","chunks":["776:static/chunks/b7d461da-c24d426981069a69.js","358:static/chunks/ae573a17-86c3c0dbf6820279.js","11:static/chunks/11-ada55797f12a86c7.js","414:static/chunks/414-737d93b2fc27a9fe.js","553:static/chunks/553-0c921218202d70d5.js","798:static/chunks/app/privacy/layout-f55345026eeff814.js"],"name":"","async":false} 8:[["$","html",null,{"lang":"en","children":["$","body",null,{"className":"__className_f62b62","children":[["$","script",null,{"type":"application/ld+json","dangerouslySetInnerHTML":{"__html":"{\"@context\":\"https://schema.org\",\"@type\":\"WebPage\",\"name\":\"course: Create virtual school, teach or learn in-demand skills online\",\"description\":\"The all-in-one platform for quality virtual education. Achieve global excellence when you create, teach or learn on course\",\"mainEntity\":{\"@type\":\"Product\",\"name\":\"mycourse: Create virtual school, teach or learn in-demand skills online\",\"description\":\"The all-in-one platform for quality virtual education. Achieve global excellence when you create, teach or learn on mycourse\",\"image\":\"https://www.mytocourse.com/favicon.png\",\"brand\":{\"@type\":\"Organization\",\"name\":\"mycourse\"},\"aggregateRating\":{\"@type\":\"AggregateRating\",\"ratingValue\":\"4.5\",\"ratingCount\":\"100\"},\"review\":{\"@type\":\"Review\",\"reviewRating\":{\"@type\":\"Rating\",\"ratingValue\":\"4.5\"},\"author\":{\"@type\":\"Person\",\"name\":\"Geeta Vasandani\"}}}}"}}],["$","$Lb",null,{"children":["$","$Lc",null,{"parallelRouterKey":"children","segmentPath":["children"],"error":"$undefined","errorStyles":"$undefined","loading":"$undefined","loadingStyles":"$undefined","hasLoading":false,"template":["$","$Ld",null,{}],"templateStyles":"$undefined","notFound":"$undefined","notFoundStyles":"$undefined","asNotFound":"$undefined","childProp":{"current":[[["$","section",null,{"className":"page_hero__d6UKW","children":[["$","$Le",null,{}],["$","header",null,{"className":"hero_herocontainer__tFeVa","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"container","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"hero_herocontent__fsDpb","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"hero_heroleft__fncL_","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"hero_image__TuldE","children":["$","$Lf",null,{"src":"/landing/heroimage.webp","alt":"learning student","width":"1000","height":"500","priority":true}]}]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"hero_heroright__yfW3d","children":[["$","h1",null,{"children":"The all-in-one\n platform for\n virtual education"}],["$","p",null,{"children":"Elevate beyond old  settings and achieve\n global excellence when you create \n your school with mycourse."}],["$","div",null,{"className":"hero_buttons__q_jp0","children":[["$","$L10",null,{"href":"create-with-mycourse","children":["$","button",null,{"children":" Get started"}]}],["$","$L10",null,{"href":"/calender","children":["$","button",null,{"className":"hero_second__GBm37","children":" Request a demo â†’"}]}]]}]]}]]}]}]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"coming_content__nr6uk","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"container","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"coming_text__8gDdL","children":[" ",["$","span",null,{"className":"coming_blue__DeuYs","children":"Coming soon:"}]," ",["$","span",null,{"children:" make the learning process more enjoyable and interactive."}]," "]}]}]}]]}],["$","section",null,{"className":"world_world__W0u6K","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"container","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"world_worldcontent__Qef83","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"world_worldright__SCnc0","children":[["$","h2",null,{"children":["Your Dreams Are ",["$","br",null,{}],"Possible Beyond Walls"]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"world_worldside__yAZrh","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"world_description__LIP1F","children":[["$","$Lf",null,{"src":"/svg/bag.svg","alt":"bag icon","width":30,"height":30}],["$","p",null,{"children":["Join at no cost. ",["$","br",null,{}],"Create an account by selecting the category you belong to."]}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"world_description__LIP1F","children":[["$","$Lf",null,{"src":"/svg/wifi.svg","alt":" wifi icon","width":30,"height":30}],["$","p",null,{"children":["Create, Teach or Learn Anywhere, Anytime.",["$","br",null,{}],"Whether youâ€™re seeking to learn  skills, upskill your workforce, teach what you love or take your academy virtual, our platform is built for you."]}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"world_description__LIP1F","children":[["$","$Lf",null,{"src":"/svg/money.svg","alt":"money icon","width":30,"height":30}],["$","p",null,{"children":["Increase Your Earning Power.",["$","br",null,{}]," double your income with our expert-led courses or transform your business with our Business suite tools and earn from a global audience."]}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"world_buttons__Dh1_H","children":["$","$L10",null,{"href":"/product","children":["$","button",null,{"children":" Get started"}]}]}]]}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"world_worldleft__lgdjX","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"world_image__uRGBm","children":["$","$Lf",null,{"src":"/landing/world.webp","alt":"coachsuccessojo","width":"800","height":"600","priority":true}]}]}]]}]}]}],["$","section",null,{"className":"grid_grid__ZP0Zo","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"container","children":["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_gridcontainer___S59T","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_gridheader__9EiLG","children":["$","p",null,{"children":["People use ",["$","span",null,{"children":"my course"}]," to"]}]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_gridcontent__nH0Gc","children":[["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_box__mkFoz","children":["$","$Lf",null,{"src":"/landing/woman.webp","alt":"a woman in front of her laptop doing thumbs up","width":"700","height":"300","priority":true}]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_box__mkFoz grid_blue__7yRDv","children":[["$","p",null,{"children":"Create Virtual School"}],["$","span",null,{"children":"Transform your traditional school, institution, or academy into a virtual school and reach more students globally. Our all-in-one business suite is everything your business needs to create, manage and market your virtual school efficiently."}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_link__gqlo9","children":["$","$L10",null,{"href":"/product","children":"learn more"}]}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_box__mkFoz grid_brown__acHRF","children":[["$","p",null,{"children":"Teach Courses"}],["$","span",null,{"children":"Monetize your knowledge as an independent teacher. Our comprehensive virtual tools are the ultimate solution you need to run your Courses and enroll students globally."}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_link__gqlo9","children":["$","$L10",null,{"href":"/product","children":"learn more"}]}]]}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_box__mkFoz grid_grey__KRQnK","children":[["$","p",null,{"children":"Create limitless opportunities "}],["$","span",null,{"children":"Our unified platform enables educators to provide personalized online learning experience to learners which is accessible via any device , from any location and at any time"}],["$","div",null,{"className":"grid_link__gqlo9","children":["$","$L10",null
```

I've tried to redeploy the app but the issue persists. I know it's not an issue with my browser because it affects everyone who has used the site.